# How to prevent duplicate form submit with browser refresh

Tags: html, forms

I use invision power board n i added little plugin for admin control panel. In this plugin is for changes some value in DB i added form. When i submited form all ok, but when i reload all page with F5, the  form submited again.

there is my code

```
<form method="post" id='xp_form' name='xp_form' enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" style='margin: 5px;'>
                    <label style='font-weight: bold;'>New value</label>
                    <p style='margin-top: 3px;'>
                        <input size="5" maxlength="7" name="xpValue" value="" tabindex="1" style='width: 98%; border-radius: 7px;'>
                    </p>
                    <fieldset style='text-align: center;border-top: 1px solid #ccc;margin-top:5px;'>
                        <input value='Cancel' name='xn_value' onclick='closeEdit()' type='button' style='padding: 4px;cursor: pointer;-webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;border-color: #2b2b2b;'> &nbsp;
                        <input value=' Save ' type='button' onclick='return testPost()' style='padding: 4px;cursor: pointer;-webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;border-color: #2b2b2b;'>
                        </fieldset>
                </form>
```

and javascript code for form submiting

```
document.forms["xp_form"].submit(); //first submit
                        document.forms["xp_form"].reset(); //and then reset the form values
```

I can't redirect to the another page or disable submit button. Let me explain. I use cms. For for dashboard i added plugin ->[image](http://ecogis.comyr.com/2013-07-20_1043.png). When admin selected row and click on the button with pencil icon showing popup window. In this window admin can edit value and then save value and then edit others records

Comment: If you POSTed the form and try to refresh the page, your browser is supposed to show a confirmation for form resubmission, so why is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to a non-submitted page is one of the easiest ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript anyway, you can disable "submit" button and do an AJAX post to the server. If request fails you can enable button again, if it succeed you can redirect user without enabling button.

The secend option is to write server code in way that when post data came you process the form and send redirection to user for another page which does not support post (like "thank you" page).

Comment: I can't redirect to the another page or disable submit button. Let me explain. I use cms. For for dashboard i added plugin -> image [link]http://ecogis.comyr.com/2013-07-20_1043.png. When admin selected row and click on the button with pencil icon showing popup window. In this window admin can edit value and then save value and then edit others records

Comment: If you cannot change server code (for redirecting), and you cannot change the client code (javascript in browser for disabling the button) - I do not know what else can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code processing the POSted value, you can allow resubmission BUT only update the database value if it is different than the previous value posted.

To do this you need to remember the previous value, perhaps by using a session or cookie or maybe a hidden input which each time stores the value (or maybe use md5(value)) which is POSTed.  In your processing you can then compare the received value with the previous remembered value and only call the database update code if these values are different.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do and it works perfectly fine. I submit the data to a server-side handler, say temp.php (change to your handler). Handler stores the $_POST or $_GET variables inside session. I believe every server-side technology has some session handling. Then immediately redirect to the page where you want user to be after page submit (in php, this is done using header() call). This solves the multiple submits by refresh.

If you do not want the user to be redirected to another page, use ajax with disable/enable submit button and clearing form fields after submit.

Comment: He has already clearly said that he cannot redirect to another page nor can he  disable the submit button.

Comment: why cant the submit button be disabled?? what harm will that do? Ofcourse that is the only way if page redirection is not a thing to consider.

Comment: or, better use blockui.js to block the whole section of page or perhaps the whole page until the ajax completes. Unblock it inside ajax's success/complete callback.